# Django authentication how to log in the user to their project

Tags: django, django-views, django-authentication

If a user has multiple projects under their account, how do I authenticate the user so that the content is not only specific to their account, but to their default project.  Ideally, the project is right at the top portion of the page, inside the base template of the site, right beside the sign-out link. The user should be able to just change the project without signing out and signing back in. The request object should be loaded with the project, so I could query the contacts model like this:

```
Contact.objects.filter(project = request.project)
```

Currently, I have to do the same query like this:

```
user_project = Project.objects.get(user = request.user, project_name = 'summer')
Contact.objects.filter(project = user_project)
```

A little nudge in the right direction is much appreciated

Comment: I'm not sure what you're looking for. Can you post your Project, User and Contact models (not everything, just the foreign keys). Depending on how you have set them up, this might be achievable by something like `Contact.objects.filter(project__user=request.user, project__project_name='summer')`

Answer (score 0):

As far as you'r going to filter the query by request, so I suppose it's gonna be used in a view class. I had the same situation and I fixed it using Mixin view with Class Based View (CBV) and inherit it to all other my Views Class. And inside this Mixin abstract view class, you can add whatever you need and join it to the request.session dictionary-like object